# installing the docker for PVNet -- docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04: not found

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install the docker for [PVNet](https://github.com/zju3dv/clean-pvnet) following their instruction here but I get an error that docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04 isn't found. How should I fix this problem?

https://github.com/zju3dv/pvnet/blob/master/docker/how-to-docker.md

```
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ sudo systemctl stop docker
[sudo] password for mona: 
Warning: Stopping docker.service, but it can still be activated by:
  docker.socket
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ sudo systemctl start docker
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ docker build --network=host -t pvnet-nvidia .
[+] Building 0.4s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                             docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.07kB                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04                                                                                                                     0.3s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
   2 |     
   3 |     # Hack to not have tzdata cmdline config during build
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04: docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04: not found
```

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ uname -a
Linux ada 6.2.0-36-generic #37~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct  9 15:34:04 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(base) mona@ada:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

(base) mona@ada:~$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.6, build ed223bc
```

Here's the contents of Dockerfile:

```
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04

# Hack to not have tzdata cmdline config during build
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Amsterdam /etc/localtime

# Install python3.7 and dependencies, taken from:
# - hhttps://websiteforstudents.com/installing-the-latest-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04/
# - https://github.com/zju3dv/pvnet/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile
# - https://github.com/zju3dv/clean-pvnet
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -yq software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa && \
    apt update && \
    apt install -yq \
        nano \
        sudo \
        wget \
        curl \
        build-essential \
        cmake \
        git \
        ca-certificates \
        python3.7 \
        python3-pip \
        python-qt4 \
        libjpeg-dev \
        zip \
        unzip \
        libpng-dev \
        libeigen3-dev \
        libglfw3-dev \
        libglfw3 \
        libgoogle-glog-dev \
        libsuitesparse-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# (mini)conda
# https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/
RUN wget -q https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    sh ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ./Miniconda3-py37_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    export PATH=$PATH:/opt/conda/bin && \
    conda install conda-build

ENV PATH $PATH:/opt/conda/envs/env/bin:/opt/conda/bin

# installing PVnet dependencies (and removing pvnet again)
RUN cd /opt && \
    git clone https://github.com/zju3dv/clean-pvnet.git pvnet && \
    cd pvnet && \
    conda init bash && \
    conda create -n pvnet python=3.7 && \
    . /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    conda activate pvnet && \
    pip install --user torch==1.1.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu90/stable && \
    pip install --user Cython==0.28.2 && \
    pip install -r requirements.txt && \
    pip install --user transforms3d && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -rf pvnet

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Further, I also tried with `nvidia-docker` and still get same error:

```
(base) mona@ada:~/clean-pvnet/docker$ nvidia-docker build --network=host -t pvnet-nvidia .
[+] Building 0.4s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                             docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.07kB                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04                                                                                                                     0.4s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04
   2 |     
   3 |     # Hack to not have tzdata cmdline config during build
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04: docker.io/nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04: not found
```